# OpenApiCustomiser bean does not contain all info

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openui

With this controller definition, with a tag:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/some_path")
@Tag(name = "MyController")
public class MyController {
   ...
}
```

When trying to customize OpenApi, I can't get the value of tags:

```
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser order() {
    return openApi -> openApi.setTags(openApi.getTags() ...
```

`openApi.getTags()` always returns `null`, I was expecting a list with `MyController` tag.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OperationCustomizer, which is more relevant for your case:

```
@Bean
public OperationCustomizer operationCustomizer() {
    return (operation, handlerMethod) -> {
        operation.setTags(operation.getTags()); // to adapt
        //operation.addTagsItem("my new tag");
        return operation;
    };
}
```